# What's the meaning of "as nature intended"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sarcasm

In a discussion, a funny dog [video](http://m.youtube.com/results?q=innocent%20until%20proven%20guilty%20dog#/watch?v=e2bnkAOsyfA) was posted.

In response to the video, person A said,

> non crated dogs ftl.

Person B disagrees and said

> what

Person C replies Person B,

> It's what non-dog people say. Yeah, keeping it in a small box for 1/2 the day is exactly as nature intended and totally fair to the dog.

What does "as nature intended" mean? I have an idea, but I want to make sure. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Hey Theo, can you please tell us what you think it might mean? You say you have an idea; I wonder what that is. That would help us to answer you and improve the question :)

Comment: I think it's a sarcasm and he wants to say that it's not natural?

Comment: What does "ftl." mean?

Comment: @Bill: Presumably the normal meaning ([faster than light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light)). I'm guessing OP's video link (which I'm not intending to follow up) involves rapid transport of "non-crated" dogs. And further guessing that "non-crated" is the premium way to ship your dog - so if you're paying for the best anyway, why not pay a bit more and have it done ***really*** fast!

Comment: @Bill: You didn't read enough sci-fi in your misspent youth, obviously! :) I, on the other hand, read far too much sci-fi when I should have been practising in the local pool hall. I got addicted to the stuff, and honest-to-god I spent this afternoon re-reading [The Foundation Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series). You may like Lolita, but I find Nabokov's style somewhat turgid compared to Asimov's. Mind you, I was shocked recently to realise how badly Ben Bova writes, when I started paying attention to the words/grammar rather than the storyline.

Comment: @Fumble: I read the entire Foundation series and _I, Robot_  back in 1995 when I was in the throes of a major depressive episode. I did nothing but read sci-fi -- Asimov, _Dune_, & _Stranger in a Strange Land_ -- for a month. Didn't even go outside. I've always been a fan of Asimov's stories. I don't remember "ftl", though.

Comment: *FTL* means *faster than light* among fans of science fiction (and maybe outside that as well), but in recent slang it means *for the lose*, as opposed to *FTW*, which means *for the win*.

Comment: @BillFranke Sorry I should've clarifed, but yea like snailboat said it means *for the lose*.

Comment: @Theo: Thank you. Here's what [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for%20the%20lose) says: "The opposite of for the win. Used to describe a situation or thing that is undesirable, whether that situation was caused by the speaker or by someone else. Often shouted when someone is killed in a multiplayer game. Most commonly used by gamers, though it's gaining popularity in general online culture for anything that's disliked.
"He just shot me with a rocket launcher! For the lose!" "We have a math test tomorrow. For the lose." No wonder I didn't understand it. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "in keeping with whatever would be natural for that thing". For a dog, it would not entail staying in a small box most of the time. "As nature intended" is being used sarcastically in this case.